# Is running a legacy Spring MVC + JSP app together with an Angular app a good idea?

Tags: java, angular, spring-mvc, jsp

We have a request to migrate only a part of a legacy system to an angular 8 app.

The seniors suggest change some url in the JSP side to point to the new angular app and make the new app's layout look like the old JSP one.

The hard part is I don't know how to sync state between JSP and angular efficiently, because we must make two clients (JSP and angular) look like they are one. This include authentication, form input, navigation bar state, etc...

About authentication, the first proposed solution is cloning the login page from the JSP and expose a login api for angular app and return a jwt token. But I don't think it will work well because we must sync the login/logout status between two apps. A second proposed solution is let the old app take care the authentication and append the jwt token to every url that link to the angular app. I afraid we will have security issue and url length limitation with this approach.

Did any body have this problem before? How did you solve it? Did you suggest a full migration to angular?

Answer (score 2):

For any web application that has reached a certain size, such a migration is the only way forward as the app is too big to be replaced at once. So coexistance between old and new pages must be achieved.

The simplest approach is if each page is either entirely JSP or entirely Angular, i.e. no mix of technologies. As you have already identified, the Angular layout will need to be sufficiently close to the JSP layout so users experience it as a single app. But every time a user switches from a JSP to an Angular page, he/she will experience a delay when the Angular app and all the related data is loaded. Some effort will need to go into make is sufficiently fast.

If you need to share state (in additiona to the authentication), then you will need to implement an API in the JSP container so the Angular app can retrieve the state and modify it. You'll probably find that only a small subset of the state needs to be shared.

For the authentication, the simplest setup is if the Angular App can access all APIs using the session cookie. Then you don't need to do anything. No new authentication page is required and not JWT needs to be passed around.

If a JWT is needed, the best solution is to setup a dedicated IAM (identity and access management) responsible for authentication. It will implement the login page and it will issue the JWT. If an unauthenticated user requests a JSP page, he/she is redirected to the IAM, logs in and is redirected back to the JSP app. The JSP app validates the login. If the same user later opens an Angular page and the Angular page needs to access an API, the user will first be redirected to the IAM. As the IAM provides a SSO facility, it will detect the valid user session and immediately issue a JWT (or authentication code) without showing a login page. In both cases, a OAUTH 2 / OIDC flow is used. And both cases a well supported by many frameworks and libraries. OIDC also includes features to synchronize the logout.

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea, but legacy applications would face lift-and-shift approach to adapt to new technologies. We have done similar exercise in React.

JSP is server side processed. Are you going with Angular SSR? In case of Angular client side processing you can use session/cookie to share user info like JWT and also to handle states.

We had to migrate only issue causing slow pages to React. We utilized Redux for state. Removed entire JSP page and developed respective React component, hence api calls goes from React. Some links invoke JSP pages - few uses http  sessions for passing data. For few complex json arrays (which requires multiple appending before submitted to backend) data is stored in Redis and retrieved by backend and from any JSP page.

Entire application is deployed as single Spring boot war.

Comment: We use client side rendering angular, authentication can be synced by cookie but I'm not sure about other state. Could you write the process you've done to migrate to React in your answer?

Comment: @Hai Hong Added more info to my answer. Hope it gives some idea for managing state